# how to use obj2opengl.pl

Tags: opengl, 3d, .obj, 3d-model

Now, I have a 3d model to .obj file extension, but I use JavaScript and obj2opengl.pl.

Guide how to use the steps to export the files .h extension?

Comment: If you use Javascript, take a look at Obj->JSON converter supplied by Three.JS

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `obj2opengl.pl` – it's absolutely crazy to embedd geometry data hardcoded into your program's executable; no matter which language and target architecture you use.

Just read in the obj files directly, they're parsed easy enough.

Comment: I use the .h file, because I use the framework of the vuforai., which vuforia to show 3-d images the .h file, and texture.png is required.